# Different Xcode project for revision

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, app-id

Let say I have ProjectX which is already available on app store. Then after how many months there is a major updates. I decided to make another xcode file project which is named also as ProjectX (but newer version).

So my question is, Is this possible? Can I upload this project directly to ItunesConnect as a newer version? Is there any settings I should set that would proportion to the same settings of the current version (ex.App ID,certificates,provisioning,etc).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely, you will need to download the App's certificates from the developer portal and import them into the project. From there, you will need to change the App's version number and make sure it's bundle identifier matches the one on the App store.

Comment: so basically after I downloaded the app certificates, and on my new xcode project I'll just set the bundle identifier same as the previous project?

Comment: Correct, then when you go to archive and submit it then it should come up as a newer version of your app. Make sure you change your version number to a higher number than the one on the app store.