# Pushing a complete new xcode project app over an existing app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have the following situation. We have in the `appstore` an app. Last week we recreated the app and started from scatch. We also started a new xcode project.

My question is this. Can I just push the new project as an update of the old app that is already in the `appstore` ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 8):

I had this question yesterday [Different Xcode project for revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389464/different-xcode-project-for-revision/20389727?noredirect=1#20389727). All you have to do is download certificates, set the bundle ID to the same as the previous project and make sure the version number is higher than the previous. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, just make sure that the new project have the same Bundle identifier of old project and build by the same distribution provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you used the same bundle Id then you can upload fresh version as new update. Just keep in mind while uploading new version check both iTunes and new app build version should be same.